# Google Markers array bug - selecting the wrong marker element

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have made a API meant to fetch Electrical Vehicles Charging Points on a map and create a route.

The route should automatically add charging points if the vehicle's capacity is not enough to finish the trip.

I fetch a Json and create an array of Marker objects. This works fine.

I then pass it through a loop that should splice all markers too far from the starting point to be reached and then another loop selecting the marker closest to destination.

For a reason I do not understand, though the array seems to have been trimed correctly, the result is a marker just next to destination and totally out of range from the starting point.

I am using the following libraries from Google: Directions, Geocoding, Maps Javascript...

I hope someone can help me because I am totally stuck here.

EDIT (further explanations:

The program is meant to add a charging stopover when the travel gets longer than the vehicle capacity (which is is 220 km.)
All the eligible stopovers are shown on the map and pushed in an array (as marker objects).
The function first splice all the stopovers further than 220 km. from the array, then in another loop I chose the stopover closest to destination.
But, if you look closer at the route you will see the charging stopover (point B) is actually 550 km. from departure and 2 km. from arrival.
This Marker should have been spliced and not be in the array anymore.

```
function selectMarkerClosestToDestination(vehicle) {
   //Selecting the closest marker to destination as long as it is not out of the vehicle capacity range
   //CURRENTLY BUGGED
   let waypoints = chargingPointsMarkers;

   for (let x = waypoints.length -1; x > 0; x--) {
       if(calculateDistance(waypoints[x], start) > (vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)){
           console.log(calculateDistance(waypoints[x], start))
           console.log(vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)
           waypoints.splice(x, 1)
           console.log(waypoints)
       }
   }

   console.log(waypoints)

   for (let x = waypoints.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
       if (calculateDistance(waypoints[x], end) > (calculateDistance(waypoints[x-1], end))) {
           waypoints.splice(x, 1);
       } else {
           waypoints.splice(x - 1, 1);
       }
   }
   console.log(waypoints)
   return waypoints[0];
}

function calculateDistance(p1, p2) {
   //Uses the Google geometry library to calculate distance between two Markers
   let a = p1.getPosition();
   let b = p2.getPosition();

   let distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a, b) / 1000).toFixed(2);
   return distance;
}
```

This is the full code (code snippet):

```js
let map;
let mapCenter = { lat: 59.428, lng: 24.76};
let start;
let end;
let chargingPointsMarkers = [];
let markerArray = [];
let stopoverMarkers = []
let vehicle1 = {capacity: 33, status: 33, consumption: 6.6666} //1KW = 6.6666 Km; Capacity in KM = status*consumption;

function initMap(listener) {
   //Create the map, the DirectionsService, the DirectionsRenderer and an eventListener for the GO button
   //If I chose to implement a detailed steps display it would also be created here
   const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   const mapOptions = {
       center: mapCenter,
       zoom: 7,
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

   const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});

   //const stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
       launcher(geocoder, directionsRenderer, directionsService);
   });
}


async function launcher(geocoder, directionsRenderer, directionsService){
   //the method is used to be launched by the eventListener
   //it sets up the start and end points, fetches the EV markers and launches the route calculation process though a callback function
   resetMarkers();
   const startEndPointsArray =  await setupRoutingProcess(geocoder);
   await callbackHandler(startEndPointsArray,directionsRenderer,
       directionsService, calculateAndDisplayRoute);
}

function setMapOnAll(map){
   // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
   for (let i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
       markerArray[i].setMap(map);
   }
}

function clearMarkers() {
   // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
   setMapOnAll(null);
}

function resetMarkers(){
   // Pushes all visible markers to a same array,
   // launches the different reset processes and
   // deletes all markers in the arrays by removing references to them.
   for (let i = 0; i < chargingPointsMarkers.length; i++) {
       markerArray.push(chargingPointsMarkers[i])
   }
   chargingPointsMarkers = [];

   for (let j = 0; j < stopoverMarkers.length; j++) {
           markerArray.push(stopoverMarkers[j])
   }
   stopoverMarkers = [];

   clearMarkers();

   markerArray = []
}

async function setupRoutingProcess(geocoder){
   //launches the setGeocodeAddress method for both start and end points and stores them in an array
   start = await setGeocodeAddress(geocoder, map, "start");
   end = await setGeocodeAddress(geocoder, map, "end");
   let startEndPointsArray = [start];
   startEndPointsArray.push(end);
   return startEndPointsArray;

}

async function setGeocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, elementId) {
   //Retrieve the addresses (strings) from the html text boxes and uses Geocoder to Google Markers objects.
   //it pushes those markers in an array later used to delete the markers on the map
   const address = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
   return new Promise(resolve => geocoder.geocode({address: address},
       (results, status) => {
           if (status === "OK") {
               resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
               const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: resultsMap,
                   position: results[0].geometry.location,
                   title: elementId,
               });
               resolve(marker)
               markerArray.push(marker);
           } else {
               alert("Trip Route finder was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
           }
       }));
}

async function callbackHandler (startEndPointsArray,
                               directionsRenderer,
                               directionsService,
                               calculateAndDisplayRoute){
   //
   let jsonChargingPoints = await setChargingStationsMarkers(startEndPointsArray, directionsRenderer,
       directionsService, calculateAndDisplayRoute);


   await createChargerPointMarkers(jsonChargingPoints)

   calculateAndDisplayRoute(
       directionsRenderer,
       directionsService,
       jsonChargingPoints
   );
}

async function setChargingStationsMarkers(startEndPointsArray, directionsRenderer,
                                         directionsService, calculateAndDisplayRoute) {
   //Creates an encoded polyline to be passed as an Url argument to limit the results
   //fetches the EV Charging Points as Json response
   const polyline = await createPolyline(startEndPointsArray);
   const baseUrl = 'https://api.openchargemap.io/v3/poi/?output=json&maxresults=200&includecomments=true';
   const queryUrl = baseUrl + '&polyline=' + polyline + '&distance=50';
   let data  = await fetch(queryUrl)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((data) => {return data})
   return data;
}

async function createPolyline(startEndPointsArray){
   //Creates a polyline and encodes it
   try {
       position = startEndPointsArray[0].getPosition();
       position2 = startEndPointsArray[1].getPosition();
       const initialPath = [position, position2];
       const poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
           path: initialPath,
           strokeColor: '#ff0000',
           strokeOpacity: 0.00001,
           strokeWeight: 0,
       });

       const path = poly.getPath();
       const encodedPath = await google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);
       return encodedPath;
   }catch (error){
       throw error ('Failed to create polyline');
   }
}

function createChargerPointMarkers(jsonChargingPoints) {
   //Loop through the Json response and launch the PlaceMarkers function
   for (let x = 0; x < jsonChargingPoints.length; x++) {
       const LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsonChargingPoints[x].AddressInfo.Latitude), parseFloat(jsonChargingPoints[x].AddressInfo.Longitude));
       placeMarker(LatLng);
   }
}

function placeMarker(location) {
   //Convert the Json response elements to Google Markers, places them on the Map and pushes them to an array.
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: location,
       map,
       draggable: false,
   });
   chargingPointsMarkers.push(marker)
}

async function calculateAndDisplayRoute(
   directionsRenderer,
   directionsService,
   jsonChargingPoints,
   stepDisplay,
   map) {

   if (!compareVehicleCapacityToDistance(vehicle1, start)) {
       setChargeCheckpoint(vehicle1)
   }

   directionsService.route(setRequest(),
       function (result, status) {
           if (status === "OK") {
               directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
               // showSteps(result, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
           } else {
               window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
           }
       });
}

function setRequest(){
   //prepares the request sent to the Directions service
   let stopovers = [];
   for (let x = 0; x < stopoverMarkers.length; x++){
       let latLng = stopoverMarkers[x].getPosition();
       let waypoint = {
           location: latLng,
           stopover: true
       };
       stopovers.push(waypoint)
   }

   const request = {
       origin: start.getPosition(),
       destination: end.getPosition(),
       waypoints: stopovers,
       travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
       unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
   };
   return request;
}

function compareVehicleCapacityToDistance(vehicle, p1){
   //Checks if the distance to destination is greater than the vehicle capacity
   if (calculateDistance(p1, end) > (vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)){
       return false
   }return true;
}

function setChargeCheckpoint(vehicle){
   //launches the function selecting the closest marker to destination
   //Setting a marker of the selected marker on the map (might be redundant)
   //Pushes it to markerArray for later deletion (might be redundant)
   //Pushes it to stopoverMarkers to be used by the Directions service to setup a route
   let waypoint = selectMarkerClosestToDestination(vehicle);
   const waypointLocation = waypoint.getPosition();
   const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: waypointLocation,
       stopover: true,
       draggable: false,
       title: "EV charging stopover"
   });
   markerArray.push(marker)
   stopoverMarkers.push(marker)
}



function selectMarkerClosestToDestination(vehicle) {
   //Selecting the closest marker to destination as long as it is not out of the vehicle capacity range
   //CURRENTLY BUGGED
   let waypoints = chargingPointsMarkers;

   for (let x = waypoints.length -1; x > 0; x--) {
       if(calculateDistance(waypoints[x], start) > (vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)){
           console.log(calculateDistance(waypoints[x], start))
           console.log(vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)
           waypoints.splice(x, 1)
           console.log(waypoints)
       }
   }

   console.log(waypoints)

   for (let x = waypoints.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
       if (calculateDistance(waypoints[x], end) > (calculateDistance(waypoints[x-1], end))) {
           waypoints.splice(x, 1);
       } else {
           waypoints.splice(x - 1, 1);
       }
   }
   console.log(waypoints)
   return waypoints[0];
}

function calculateDistance(p1, p2) {
   //Uses the Google geometry library to calculate distance between two Markers
   let a = p1.getPosition();
   let b = p2.getPosition();

   let distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a, b) / 1000).toFixed(2);
   return distance;
}

function showSteps(directionResult, stepDisplay, map) {
   // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's infowindow.
   // Also attach the marker to an array so we can keep track of it and remove it
   // when calculating new routes.
   //NOT CURRENTLY IMPLEMENTED/USED
   const myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];

   for (let i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
       const marker = (markerArray[i] =
           markerArray[i] || new google.maps.Marker());
       marker.setMap(map);
       marker.setPosition(myRoute.steps[i].start_location);
       attachInstructionText(
           stepDisplay,
           marker,
           myRoute.steps[i].instructions,
           map
       );
   }
}

function attachInstructionText(stepDisplay, marker, text, map) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
       // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on, containing the text
       // of the step.
       //NOT CURRENTLY IMPLEMENTED/USED
       stepDisplay.setContent(text);
       stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
   });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
      * element that contains the map. */
#map {
   height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 25%;
   z-index: 5;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "Roboto", "sans-serif";
   line-height: 30px;
   padding-left: 10px;
}

#warnings-panel {
   width: 100%;
   height: 10%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>EV Trip Route Finder</title>
   <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
   <script
           src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
           defer
   ></script>
   <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="floating-panel" >
   <b>Start: </b>
   <input id="start" type="text" value="Tallinn">
   <b>End: </b>
   <input id="end" type="text" value="Vilnius">
   <input id="submit" type="button" value="GO" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
&nbsp;
<div id="warnings-panel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working code snippet, using a stack overflow code snippet, or a jsfiddle / codepen / etc? This should include an example route, position, and the expected list of markers. Anything we'd need to be able to reproduce the issue (that is a [mcve]).

Comment: All the pieces for a StackSnippet were there, created a working StackSnippet in the question.  However it would be helpful if you (the OP) could describe the issue in more detail, that code creates a route and a whole bunch of (what I assume are) EV charging markers.  How do we see the issue?  Please provide debugging details.

Comment: @geocodezip The program is meant to add a charging stopover when the travel gets longer than the vehicle capacity (220 km.)

All the eligible stopovers are shown on the map and pushed in an array (as marker objects). The function first splice all the stopovers further than 220 km. from the array, then in another loop I chose the stopover closest to destination.

But, if you look closer at the route you will see the charging stopover (point B) is actually 550 km. from departure and 2 km. from arrival. This Marker should have been spliced and not be in the array anymore.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I think all the elements are there already but here it is in jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/Reivilo85k/4u05g36a/2/

Thanks for looking at my problem

Comment: My question is how to debug your code.  How do you calculate the correct marker to use as a waypoint?  You say it is calculating the wrong waypoint, which waypoint does it select?  Which one do you expect it to select?  I don't see any useful debugging information in the console output.

Comment: @geocodezip

I take an array of markers, splice all the ones further than 220 km from the start, then among those select the one closest to destination.

If you run the snipet and zoom you will see B, the stopover, is very close to C , the destination. It is also 550 km from the start.

It should not be possible.

Comment: Sounds to me like your code is doing exactly what you describe.  It is picking the marker that is greater that 220 km from the start which is closest to the destination.

Comment: @geocodezip It should be the opposite, it should be any point lesser than 220 km. closest to destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one small mistake in your code, that is in your `for` loop where you exclude waypoints that are over the vehicle capacity.

Basically, you are doing the following, which as you can see doesn't output what you'd expect:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  console.log(a[i])
}
```

Instead, you want to use `i >= 0` to loop through all elements within your array:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(a[i])
}
```

Changing this one statement seems to correct the issue because you were not iterating through the entire array and therefore you were leaving 1 element at 528km from start in the first loop, which would end up being the one you select in the second loop (in the `selectMarkerClosestToDestination()` function).

```js
let map;
let mapCenter = { lat: 59.428, lng: 24.76};
let start;
let end;
let chargingPointsMarkers = [];
let markerArray = [];
let stopoverMarkers = []
let vehicle1 = {capacity: 33, status: 33, consumption: 6.6666} //1KW = 6.6666 Km; Capacity in KM = status*consumption;

function initMap(listener) {
   //Create the map, the DirectionsService, the DirectionsRenderer and an eventListener for the GO button
   //If I chose to implement a detailed steps display it would also be created here
   const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   const mapOptions = {
       center: mapCenter,
       zoom: 7,
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

   const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});

   //const stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
       launcher(geocoder, directionsRenderer, directionsService);
   });
}


async function launcher(geocoder, directionsRenderer, directionsService){
   //the method is used to be launched by the eventListener
   //it sets up the start and end points, fetches the EV markers and launches the route calculation process though a callback function
   resetMarkers();
   const startEndPointsArray =  await setupRoutingProcess(geocoder);
   await callbackHandler(startEndPointsArray,directionsRenderer,
       directionsService, calculateAndDisplayRoute);
}

function setMapOnAll(map){
   // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
   for (let i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
       markerArray[i].setMap(map);
   }
}

function clearMarkers() {
   // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
   setMapOnAll(null);
}

function resetMarkers(){
   // Pushes all visible markers to a same array,
   // launches the different reset processes and
   // deletes all markers in the arrays by removing references to them.
   for (let i = 0; i < chargingPointsMarkers.length; i++) {
       markerArray.push(chargingPointsMarkers[i])
   }
   chargingPointsMarkers = [];

   for (let j = 0; j < stopoverMarkers.length; j++) {
           markerArray.push(stopoverMarkers[j])
   }
   stopoverMarkers = [];

   clearMarkers();

   markerArray = []
}

async function setupRoutingProcess(geocoder){
   //launches the setGeocodeAddress method for both start and end points and stores them in an array
   start = await setGeocodeAddress(geocoder, map, "start");
   end = await setGeocodeAddress(geocoder, map, "end");
   let startEndPointsArray = [start];
   startEndPointsArray.push(end);
   return startEndPointsArray;

}

async function setGeocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, elementId) {
   //Retrieve the addresses (strings) from the html text boxes and uses Geocoder to Google Markers objects.
   //it pushes those markers in an array later used to delete the markers on the map
   const address = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
   return new Promise(resolve => geocoder.geocode({address: address},
       (results, status) => {
           if (status === "OK") {
               resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
               const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: resultsMap,
                   position: results[0].geometry.location,
                   title: elementId,
               });
               resolve(marker)
               markerArray.push(marker);
           } else {
               alert("Trip Route finder was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
           }
       }));
}

async function callbackHandler (startEndPointsArray,
                               directionsRenderer,
                               directionsService,
                               calculateAndDisplayRoute){
   //
   let jsonChargingPoints = await setChargingStationsMarkers(startEndPointsArray, directionsRenderer,
       directionsService, calculateAndDisplayRoute);


   await createChargerPointMarkers(jsonChargingPoints)

   calculateAndDisplayRoute(
       directionsRenderer,
       directionsService,
       jsonChargingPoints
   );
}

async function setChargingStationsMarkers(startEndPointsArray, directionsRenderer,
                                         directionsService, calculateAndDisplayRoute) {
   //Creates an encoded polyline to be passed as an Url argument to limit the results
   //fetches the EV Charging Points as Json response
   const polyline = await createPolyline(startEndPointsArray);
   const baseUrl = 'https://api.openchargemap.io/v3/poi/?output=json&maxresults=200&includecomments=true';
   const queryUrl = baseUrl + '&polyline=' + polyline + '&distance=50';
   let data  = await fetch(queryUrl)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((data) => {return data})
   return data;
}

async function createPolyline(startEndPointsArray){
   //Creates a polyline and encodes it
   try {
       position = startEndPointsArray[0].getPosition();
       position2 = startEndPointsArray[1].getPosition();
       const initialPath = [position, position2];
       const poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
           path: initialPath,
           strokeColor: '#ff0000',
           strokeOpacity: 0.00001,
           strokeWeight: 0,
       });

       const path = poly.getPath();
       const encodedPath = await google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);
       return encodedPath;
   }catch (error){
       throw error ('Failed to create polyline');
   }
}

function createChargerPointMarkers(jsonChargingPoints) {
   //Loop through the Json response and launch the PlaceMarkers function
   for (let x = 0; x < jsonChargingPoints.length; x++) {
       const LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsonChargingPoints[x].AddressInfo.Latitude), parseFloat(jsonChargingPoints[x].AddressInfo.Longitude));
       placeMarker(LatLng);
   }
}

function placeMarker(location) {
   //Convert the Json response elements to Google Markers, places them on the Map and pushes them to an array.
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: location,
       map,
       draggable: false,
   });
   chargingPointsMarkers.push(marker)
}

async function calculateAndDisplayRoute(
   directionsRenderer,
   directionsService,
   jsonChargingPoints,
   stepDisplay,
   map) {

   if (!compareVehicleCapacityToDistance(vehicle1, start)) {
       setChargeCheckpoint(vehicle1)
   }

   directionsService.route(setRequest(),
       function (result, status) {
           if (status === "OK") {
               directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
               // showSteps(result, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
           } else {
               window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
           }
       });
}

function setRequest(){
   //prepares the request sent to the Directions service
   let stopovers = [];
   for (let x = 0; x < stopoverMarkers.length; x++){
       let latLng = stopoverMarkers[x].getPosition();
       let waypoint = {
           location: latLng,
           stopover: true
       };
       stopovers.push(waypoint)
   }

   const request = {
       origin: start.getPosition(),
       destination: end.getPosition(),
       waypoints: stopovers,
       travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
       unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
   };
   return request;
}

function compareVehicleCapacityToDistance(vehicle, p1){
   //Checks if the distance to destination is greater than the vehicle capacity
   if (calculateDistance(p1, end) > (vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)){
       return false
   }return true;
}

function setChargeCheckpoint(vehicle){
   //launches the function selecting the closest marker to destination
   //Setting a marker of the selected marker on the map (might be redundant)
   //Pushes it to markerArray for later deletion (might be redundant)
   //Pushes it to stopoverMarkers to be used by the Directions service to setup a route
   let waypoint = selectMarkerClosestToDestination(vehicle);
   const waypointLocation = waypoint.getPosition();
   const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: waypointLocation,
       stopover: true,
       draggable: false,
       title: "EV charging stopover"
   });
   markerArray.push(marker)
   stopoverMarkers.push(marker)
}



function selectMarkerClosestToDestination(vehicle) {
   //Selecting the closest marker to destination as long as it is not out of the vehicle capacity range
   //CURRENTLY BUGGED
   let waypoints = chargingPointsMarkers;

   for (let x = waypoints.length -1; x >= 0; x--) {
       if(calculateDistance(waypoints[x], start) > (vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)){
           console.log(calculateDistance(waypoints[x], start))
           console.log(vehicle.status*vehicle.consumption)
           waypoints.splice(x, 1)
           console.log(waypoints)
       }
   }

   console.log(waypoints)

   for (let x = waypoints.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
       if (calculateDistance(waypoints[x], end) > (calculateDistance(waypoints[x-1], end))) {
           waypoints.splice(x, 1);
       } else {
           waypoints.splice(x - 1, 1);
       }
   }
   console.log(waypoints)
   return waypoints[0];
}

function calculateDistance(p1, p2) {
   //Uses the Google geometry library to calculate distance between two Markers
   let a = p1.getPosition();
   let b = p2.getPosition();

   let distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a, b) / 1000).toFixed(2);
   return distance;
}

function showSteps(directionResult, stepDisplay, map) {
   // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's infowindow.
   // Also attach the marker to an array so we can keep track of it and remove it
   // when calculating new routes.
   //NOT CURRENTLY IMPLEMENTED/USED
   const myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];

   for (let i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
       const marker = (markerArray[i] =
           markerArray[i] || new google.maps.Marker());
       marker.setMap(map);
       marker.setPosition(myRoute.steps[i].start_location);
       attachInstructionText(
           stepDisplay,
           marker,
           myRoute.steps[i].instructions,
           map
       );
   }
}

function attachInstructionText(stepDisplay, marker, text, map) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
       // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on, containing the text
       // of the step.
       //NOT CURRENTLY IMPLEMENTED/USED
       stepDisplay.setContent(text);
       stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
   });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
      * element that contains the map. */
#map {
   height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 25%;
   z-index: 5;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "Roboto", "sans-serif";
   line-height: 30px;
   padding-left: 10px;
}

#warnings-panel {
   width: 100%;
   height: 10%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>EV Trip Route Finder</title>
   <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
   <script
           src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
           defer
   ></script>
   <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="floating-panel" >
   <b>Start: </b>
   <input id="start" type="text" value="Tallinn">
   <b>End: </b>
   <input id="end" type="text" value="Vilnius">
   <input id="submit" type="button" value="GO" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
&nbsp;
<div id="warnings-panel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ MrUpsidown Thank you so much. I should have seen this, it's such a small thing, but somehow I was blind. Really, really thank you !

Comment: It seems it helped, so please consider [accepting / upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer.